# Android FileProvider content:// uri no read permission in target app

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider, scoped-storage

I try sharing a file (of PDF type, but this is not important) present in my App1 "external_files" directory (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package.app1/files) to my App2. I'm testing this in Android 10 emulator (from Android Studio, latest), both apps use Scoped Storage and the support for legacy external storage is not enabled.

All seems to be defined by "the book", in App1 manifest:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.package.app1.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/my_paths" />
    </provider>
```

then my_paths.xml has

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Then in App1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setPackage("com.package.app2");
File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "MyFile.pdf");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.package.app1.fileprovider", file);
context.grantUriPermission("com.package.app2", uri,
                        FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(uri, "application/pdf");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

App2 has in its manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In App2: activity onCreate():

```
   Uri uri = getIntent().getData(); // The content:// uri looks correct
   if (uri != null) {
        DocumentFile docFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, uri);
        Log.d("myTag", uri.toString + ": EXISTS: ", docFile.exists(), ", can read: ", docFile.canRead());
   }
```

The output is always, no matter what I do:

```
content://com.package.app1.fileprovider/external_files/MyFile.pdf: EXISTS: true, can read: false
```

What am I doing wrong, why can't I get "can read: true"?

Comment: Is canRead() reliable? Better try to read. Open an input stream and read.

Comment: context.grantUriPermission("com.package.app2... try without that line.

Comment: Use setDataAndType() instead.

Comment: @blackapps, thank you - tried to open an input stream, it fails. When I test docFile.isFile() and docFile.isDirectory(), both return false. However the mUri member of docFile looks correct: content://com.package.app1.fileprovider/external_files/MyFile.pdf

Comment: @blackapps, thank you for trying to help, also tried setDataAndType() instead, no difference...

Comment: Does you r app have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? At runtime too?

Comment: @blackapps - you're right, canRead() is not reliable. Before getting an input stream, in a misguided attempt to prevent trying to open a stream on a directory, I was testing docFile.isFile(), and it returned false. Now I test !docFile().isDirectory() and I get a readable input stream. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by @blackapps in the very first comment was right: docFile.canRead() on a DocumentFile is not reliable, when docFile.isFile() returns false (docFile.isDirectory() also returned false, it was a regular file content from FileProvider). Despite docFile.canRead() returning false, I am able to open an InputStream on docFile object and can read it fine. Thank you, @blackapps!

Comment: This is clearly a malfunction in Android, or at least misleading documentation. I will try to send a bug report to the developers or documentation authors.

Answer (score 0):

Actually canRead() for a DocumentFile is reliable. But it checks different things than File.canRead()

Acording to DocumentsContractApi19, this is what canRead() do for a DocumentFile:

```
 public static boolean canRead(Context context, Uri self) {
        // Ignore if grant doesn't allow read
        if (context.checkCallingOrSelfUriPermission(self, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }

        // Ignore documents without MIME
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getRawType(context, self))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

My recommendation is: do not use canRead() as you would for a File. instead, try to open the uri for reading using try/catch